# Where to store global scope when using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Still a novice when it comes to using React. I'm making my first application using React Router and trying to lean more into using local state and avoiding having a lot of elements in my global scope.

However, I will need a few and I'm unsure of where I should insert the 'global' state or what the best practice is here. In the past I've always put it inside App.js, but using React Router 4 I don't even render , since my index.js file looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Should the global scope just live within Routes? Just looking for best practice suggestions!

Comment: I don't think I understand you clearly. Could you again explain your question?

Comment: Yeah sorry. There are some variables that I want to live in a 'global state' (meaning that they'll be accessible from anywhere in the application and can easily be passed down to components). In the past, I've always put this state in the App component. However, now that I'm using React Router, I don't even render the App component, instead rendering the <Routes/> component. I'm wondering if I should add a global state to the Route component because that's what is being rendered, or whether there's somewhere else it makes sense to hold the global state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using store. This is how you implement it.

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import rootReducer from "../reducers/root";
import Root from '../config/root';

let store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(promise),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Root store={store} />
    ,document.getElementById('root')
);\
```

**Root.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Index from '../components/index';
import Login from '../components/login';
import Signup from '../components/signup';

const Root = ({ store }) => {
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Index}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};

Root.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Root;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not opposed to pulling in Redux and I'm not sure I fully understand its use as opposed to regular React. When using a Redux store like this do I want to end up putting EVERYTHING inside store, or can I still use a bunch of local states and just use the store for what the high value data?

Comment: If you'd like to improve your skills I highly suggest you to watch "Modern React with Redux" by Stephen Grinder. You can find his course on udemy.

You can have local states as well as store. Developers use local states for simple ui changes like toggling accordion, navbar, etc. Although, you can create `actions/ui.js` and `reducers/ui.js` to manage ui state in store. So, you can toggle your accordion in store too.

Please put a check mark on my answer if you think this is an answer to your question.